# SVG Coloring of Rectangles

Tags: html, c++, svg

My friend has helped me build a program that will take data from a file and place it in a vector. The data will then be used to make a bar graph of temperatures. I have the code done but the part for adding color to higher temperatures is not working. So for example, colder temps are blue, as they get warmer it goes to orange and red ect. Im new to this so any help is appreciated. I have included the entire code if context is needed but the first part is is the color change part.

```
string red;
    ostringstream red_color;
    red_color << 255 - (int) temp[i];
    int red_c = (int)(255 - (int) temp[i]);
    red = red_color.str();





#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <istream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
string html_start() { return("<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<body>\n\n"); }
string html_end()   { return("\n</body>\n</html>\n\n"); }
string svg_start()  { return("<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" version=\"1.1\"   viewBox=\"0 0 1024 768\" preserveAspectRatio=\"xMinYMid meet\" >\n"); }
string svg_end()    { return("</svg>\n"); }
string svg_line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, string color);
string svg_text(int x, int y, string text, int font_size, string fill_color);
int main()
{
    ifstream fin;

fin.open("/Users/bryan/Documents/CS/Final/parsableTemps.txt");
if (fin.fail())
{
    cout << "Input file opening failed. \n";
    exit(1);
}

   vector<float> temp;
   double t;
   while (fin >> t)
   {
       temp.push_back(t);
   }

fin.close();

float low = temp[0];
float high = temp[0];

for (int i=0; i<temp.size(); i++){
if (temp[i] < low)
    low = temp[i];
if (temp[i] > high)
    high = temp[i];}

for (int j = 0; j < temp.size(); j++)
    temp[j] = (float)9/5*temp[j] + 32;

ofstream fout;
int column = 10;
int width = 5;
int i;
int temp_start = 20;

fout.open("graph.html");
fout << html_start();
fout << "<h1>Monthly Temperature Change over the Last 20 Years </h1>\n";
fout << svg_start();


fout << svg_line(temp_start, width, temp_start, 110, "black");


fout << svg_line(10, 100, 1250, 100, "black");


for (int l = 0; l < 8; l++)
    fout << svg_line(17, 90 - 10*l, temp_start, 90 - 10*l, "black");


for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++){
    string temp;
    ostringstream number;
    number << (n+1)*20;
    temp = number.str();
    fout << svg_text(5, 103 - (n+1)*20, temp , 10, "black");
}


for (int o = 0; o < 21; o++){
    string temp;
    ostringstream year;
    year << 1993 + o;
    temp = year.str();
    fout << svg_text(temp_start + 60*o - 15, 125, temp , 15, "black");
}


for (int m = 0; m < 20; m++)
    fout << svg_line(temp_start + 60 * (m + 1), 100, temp_start + 60 * (m + 1), 108,     "black");

for(i=0; i< temp.size(); i++) {
/// this is where it begins
    string red;
    ostringstream red_color;
    red_color << 255 - (int) temp[i];
    int red_c = (int)(255 - (int) temp[i]);
    red = red_color.str();
/// this is where it ends
    fout << "   <rect x=\"" << temp_start << "\" y=\"" << 100 - temp[i] << "\" width=\""     << width << "\" height=\"" << temp[i] << "\" style=\"fill:rgb(127,0,255);stroke-    width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)\"/>\n";
    temp_start += width;
}





fout << svg_end();
fout << html_end();
fout.close();

return 0;}

string svg_text(int x, int y, string text)
{
   std::ostringstream assembled_oss;
   assembled_oss << " <text x=\"" << x << "\" y=\"" << y << "\" font-size=\"20\"     fill=\"black\">" << text << "\"</text>\n";
   return(assembled_oss.str());
}

    string svg_text(int x, int y, string text, int font_size, string fill_color)
{
   std::ostringstream assembled_oss;
   assembled_oss << " <text x=\"" << x << "\" y=\"" << y << "\" font-size=\"" << font_size <<     "\"";
   assembled_oss << " fill=\"" << fill_color << "\">" << text << "</text>\n";
   return(assembled_oss.str());
}

string svg_text(int x, int y, string text, int font_size, string fill_color, string     font_family)
{
   std::ostringstream assembled_oss;
   assembled_oss << " <text x=\"" << x << "\" y=\"" << y << "\" font-size=\"" << font_size <<     "\"";
   assembled_oss << " fill=\"" << fill_color << "\" font_family=\"" << font_family << "\">" <<     text << "</text>\n";
   return(assembled_oss.str());
}

string svg_line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, string color)
{
   std::ostringstream assembled_oss;
   assembled_oss << " <line x1=\"" << x1 << "\" y1=\"" << y1 << "\" x2=\"" << x2 << "\" y2=\"" << y2 << "\"";
   assembled_oss << " stroke=\"" << color << "\" stroke-width=\"2\"/>\n";
   return(assembled_oss.str());
}

string svg_line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, string color, int width)
{
   std::ostringstream assembled_oss;
   assembled_oss << " <line x1=\"" << x1 << "\" y1=\"" << y1 << "\" x2=\"" << x2 << "\" y2=\"" << y2 << "\"";
   assembled_oss << " stroke=\"" << color << "\" stroke-width=\"" << width << "\"/>\n";
   return(assembled_oss.str());
}

string svg_rect(int x1, int y1, int width, int height)
{
   std::ostringstream assembled_oss;
   assembled_oss << " <rect x=\"" << x1 << "\" y=\"" << y1 << "\" width=\"" << width <<     "\" height=\"" << height << "\"";
   assembled_oss << " style=\"fill:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)\"/>\n";
   return(assembled_oss.str());
}
```

Comment: Could you include the expected and observed results for the inputs that provide unsatisfactory output? (as well as the input) "not working" often isn't terribly conducive to solving a problem from afar.

Comment: When i run the code, i get a series of bar graph of temperatures. This is the desired result but they all are colored blue. What i was trying to do is get a series of bar graphs that change color. For example, blue is cold, yellow is warm, and red is hot. My attempt at getting them to change red is listed first and then i have my entire code with the un-opperational part included.

Comment: So, say the first temp. is 50F it would be colored blue, the next temp would is 90F it would be colored red and ect. I tried to set it up so if it met the specifications/filter it would be colored as so

Comment: Have a closer look at the line that follows the comment `/// this is where it ends` - notice anything funny here? Namely - you've hard-coded the colour `rgb(127,0,255)` - the very same colour that all of the bars have... :p As an aside, you may wish to consider using the HSL or HSV colour-spaces. You can use the temperature and map that to a Hue. E.g 0 degrees C(or F) = Hue of 240 degrees and 100 degrees  C(or F) = Hue of 360 degrees. Once you've done this, compute r,g,b values from your calculated Hue (just use a S and V of 100%). Code to convert HSV->RGB or HSL->RGB is easy to find. :)

Comment: I didnt realize that i did that. I dont quite understand what you mean though. Im very inexperienced with coding. What i need is for the default color to be blue but when it encounters a temp higher than the limit it would override the default.

Comment: :grin: - I made a few changes. **1.** moved the loop that converts the temps from deg C-> deg F to _above_ the loop that calculates the high and low temps. **2.** changed the `red_color` calc to: `red_color << (int) ( ((temp[i] - low) / (high-low) ) * 255);` and **3.** changed the line I mentioned earlier to `fout << "   <rect x=\"" << temp_start << "\" y=\"" << 100 - temp[i] << "\" width=\""     << width << "\" height=\"" << temp[i] << "\" style=\"fill:rgb(" << red << ",0,255);stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)\"/>\n";` - the result? A graph that goes from blue 4 coldest to magenta 4 hottest.

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry to bug you again but can the magenta be closer to red.

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated the solution with use of the hsvToRgb function I mentioned and the produced output. Hope its helpful. Notice how much easier it is to just modify a single channel (Hue) than it is to manipulate the colour in RGB space.

Answer (score 0):

Further to the comments I made earlier, here is the code I've used and the data I've given as input.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <istream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
string html_start()
{
    return("<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<body>\n\n");
}
string html_end()
{
    return("\n</body>\n</html>\n\n");
}
string svg_start()
{
    return("<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" version=\"1.1\" viewBox=\"0 0 1024 768\" preserveAspectRatio=\"xMinYMid meet\" >\n");
}
string svg_end()
{
    return("</svg>\n");
}
string svg_line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, string color);
string svg_text(int x, int y, string text, int font_size, string fill_color);

int main()
{
    ifstream fin;

 //   fin.open("/Users/bryan/Documents/CS/Final/parsableTemps.txt");
    fin.open("temps.txt");
    if (fin.fail())
    {
        cout << "Input file opening failed. \n";
        exit(1);
    }

    vector<float> temp;
    double t;
    while (fin >> t)
    {
        temp.push_back(t);
    }

    fin.close();

    for (int j = 0; j < temp.size(); j++)
        temp[j] = (float)9/5*temp[j] + 32;


    float low = temp[0];
    float high = temp[0];

    for (int i=0; i<temp.size(); i++)
    {
        if (temp[i] < low)
            low = temp[i];
        if (temp[i] > high)
            high = temp[i];
    }


    ofstream fout;
    int column = 10;
    int width = 5;
    int i;
    int temp_start = 20;

    fout.open("graph.html");
    fout << html_start();
    fout << "<h1>Monthly Temperature Change over the Last 20 Years </h1>\n";
    fout << svg_start();


    fout << svg_line(temp_start, width, temp_start, 110, "black");


    fout << svg_line(10, 100, 1250, 100, "black");


    for (int l = 0; l < 8; l++)
        fout << svg_line(17, 90 - 10*l, temp_start, 90 - 10*l, "black");


    for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++)
    {
        string temp;
        ostringstream number;
        number << (n+1)*20;
        temp = number.str();
        fout << svg_text(5, 103 - (n+1)*20, temp , 10, "black");
    }


    for (int o = 0; o < 21; o++)
    {
        string temp;
        ostringstream year;
        year << 1993 + o;
        temp = year.str();
        fout << svg_text(temp_start + 60*o - 15, 125, temp , 15, "black");
    }

    for (int m = 0; m < 20; m++)
        fout << svg_line(temp_start + 60 * (m + 1), 100, temp_start + 60 * (m + 1), 108,     "black");

    for(i=0; i< temp.size(); i++)
    {
/// this is where it begins
        string red;
        ostringstream red_color;

//        red_color << 255 - (int) temp[i];
        red_color << (int) ( ((temp[i] - low) / (high-low) ) * 255);
//        red_color << (int) ( (255 * temp[i]) / high);

        red = red_color.str();
/// this is where it ends
//        fout << "   <rect x=\"" << temp_start << "\" y=\"" << 100 - temp[i] << "\" width=\""     << width << "\" height=\"" << temp[i] << "\" style=\"fill:rgb(127,0,255);stroke-    width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)\"/>\n";
        fout << "   <rect x=\"" << temp_start << "\" y=\"" << 100 - temp[i] << "\" width=\""     << width << "\" height=\"" << temp[i] << "\" style=\"fill:rgb(" << red << ",0,255);stroke-    width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)\"/>\n";
        temp_start += width;
    }

    fout << svg_end();
    fout << html_end();
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}

string svg_text(int x, int y, string text)
{
    std::ostringstream assembled_oss;
    assembled_oss << " <text x=\"" << x << "\" y=\"" << y << "\" font-size=\"20\"     fill=\"black\">" << text << "\"</text>\n";
    return(assembled_oss.str());
}

string svg_text(int x, int y, string text, int font_size, string fill_color)
{
    std::ostringstream assembled_oss;
    assembled_oss << " <text x=\"" << x << "\" y=\"" << y << "\" font-size=\"" << font_size <<     "\"";
    assembled_oss << " fill=\"" << fill_color << "\">" << text << "</text>\n";
    return(assembled_oss.str());
}

string svg_text(int x, int y, string text, int font_size, string fill_color, string     font_family)
{
    std::ostringstream assembled_oss;
    assembled_oss << " <text x=\"" << x << "\" y=\"" << y << "\" font-size=\"" << font_size <<     "\"";
    assembled_oss << " fill=\"" << fill_color << "\" font_family=\"" << font_family << "\">" <<     text << "</text>\n";
    return(assembled_oss.str());
}

string svg_line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, string color)
{
    std::ostringstream assembled_oss;
    assembled_oss << " <line x1=\"" << x1 << "\" y1=\"" << y1 << "\" x2=\"" << x2 << "\" y2=\"" << y2 << "\"";
    assembled_oss << " stroke=\"" << color << "\" stroke-width=\"2\"/>\n";
    return(assembled_oss.str());
}

string svg_line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, string color, int width)
{
    std::ostringstream assembled_oss;
    assembled_oss << " <line x1=\"" << x1 << "\" y1=\"" << y1 << "\" x2=\"" << x2 << "\" y2=\"" << y2 << "\"";
    assembled_oss << " stroke=\"" << color << "\" stroke-width=\"" << width << "\"/>\n";
    return(assembled_oss.str());
}

string svg_rect(int x1, int y1, int width, int height)
{
    std::ostringstream assembled_oss;
    assembled_oss << " <rect x=\"" << x1 << "\" y=\"" << y1 << "\" width=\"" << width <<     "\" height=\"" << height << "\"";
    assembled_oss << " style=\"fill:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)\"/>\n";
    return(assembled_oss.str());
}
```

**temps.txt**

```
10
15
20
25
30
35
40
45
```

**cropped section of the output**

[image]

As for my earlier mention of using a different colour-space, I'm going to assume that I want a blue (rgb 0,0,255) value for the coldest temperature in the input and a red (rgb 255,0,0) value for the hottest temperature in the input.

To compute the rgb value for each bar, I'd use the following calculation:

```
float Hue = (curTemp - coldestTemp) / (hottestTemp-coldestTemp);
Hue *= 360 - 240;
Hue += 240;

float Sat = 100;
float Val = 100;
```

You now have a hue that ranges from 240 for the coldest, up to 360 for the hottest temp.
From there, I'd get r,g,b values by converting HSV --> RGB using the following function.

```
// Input: h, s, v in range [0..1] (typical ranges are 0..360, 0..100, 0..100)
// Outputs: r, g, b in range [0..1] (typical ranges are 0..255, 0..255, 0..255)
void hsvToRgb(float h, float s, float v, float *r, float *g, float *b)
{
     int i;
     float aa, bb, cc, f;

     if (s == 0.0) // greyscale
        *r = *g = *b = v;
     else
     {
         if (h == 1.0) h = 0.0;
         h *= 6.0;
         i = floor(h);
         f = h - (float)i;
         aa = v * (1.0 - s);
         bb = v * (1.0 - (s * f));
         cc = v * (1.0 - (s * (1.0 - f)));
         switch(i)
         {
           case 0: *r = v; *g = cc; *b = aa; break;
           case 1: *r = bb; *g = v; *b = aa; break;
           case 2: *r = aa; *g = v; *b = cc; break;
           case 3: *r = aa; *g = bb; *b = v; break;
           case 4: *r = cc; *g = aa; *b = v; break;
           case 5: *r = v; *g = aa; *b = bb; break;
         }
     }
}
```

Use:

```
float r, g, b;
hsvToRgb( Hue/360.0, Sat/100.0, Val/100.0, &r, &g, &b);
r *= 255.0;
g *= 255.0;
b *= 255.0;
```

I'd then plug these values of rgb into the code that outputs the colour to use for each bar.

You'd just have to do the initial calculation a little differently if you wanted blue = 0deg F and red = 100deg F

Namely:

```
Hue = curTemp / (100-0);
Hue *= (360 - 240);
Hue += 240;
```

This will give funny results if you use temps outside the 0-100 deg range. You'd need to clamp Hue to no lower than 240 and no higher than 360, *or* use a larger range than 0-100.

There's lots of good info available on why the HSV or HSL colour-spaces are better to use for computing a desired colour than RGB (mainly, they produce an intuitive means to change the colour) Unfortunately, monitors work with RGB, so you need to convert them to RGB for viewing purposes.

Heres the HSV colour-wheel for reference (dialog courtesy of Gimp 2.8.0):

[image]

**UPDATE:**
Further to the code I left above, (note particularly the conversion to deg F *before* computing the min/max temps) I've modified the last for-loop in the program and added the hsvToRgb function I mentioned. I've used the same data. The output now appears like this:

[image]

Here's the loop itself:

```
for(i=0; i< temp.size(); i++)
{
    ostringstream rgbColor;
    string col;

    float Hue = (temp[i]-low) / (high-low);         // set Hue in range [0..1]
    Hue *= (360 - 240);                             // make Hue in range [0..120]
    Hue += 240;                                     // make Hue in range [240..360]

    float Sat = 100.0;
    float Val = 100.0;
    float r, g, b;

    hsvToRgb( Hue/360.0, Sat/100.0, Val/100.0, &r, &g, &b);
    r *= 255.0;
    g *= 255.0;
    b *= 255.0;

    rgbColor << (int)r << "," << (int)g << "," << (int)b;
    col = rgbColor.str();

    fout << "<rect x=\"" << temp_start << "\" y=\"" << 100 - temp[i] << "\" width=\"" << width << "\" height=\"" << temp[i] << "\" style=\"fill:rgb(" << col << ");stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)\"/>\n";
    temp_start += width;
}
```